# ruby-on-rails - link with custom action on object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a list of objects and for each object I have 2 links - "Delete" and "Done". Like this:

1) Buy tomatoes;  Delete | Done
2) Wash the car;  Delete | Done

But my custom action `done` don't work. I need your help, how can I make my action and what code should I write in file `routes.rb`?

Controller:

```
def done
   @task = Task.where(id: params[:id])
   @task.done = true

   redirect_to "/tasks"
end
```

Link in view file:

```
<%= link_to "Done", {:controller => :tasks, :action => :done, :id => task.id}%>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller:

```
def done
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  @task.done = true
  @task.save! # Use the 'bang' method or check the return value
  redirect_to tasks_path
end
```

In routes.rb:

```
resources :tasks do
  get :done, on: :member
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= link_to 'Done', done_task_path(task.id) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning the value but not saving the data. So save the data using `@task.save`

```
def done
   @task = Task.where(id: params[:id])
   @task.done = true
   @task.save

   redirect_to "/tasks"
end
```